# Is using both observer.unobserve and observer.disconnect redundant

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is using both observer.unobserve and observer.disconnect redundant? Should I only use one?

I'm using the IntersectionObserver in a useEffect. This is the clean up function for my useEffect.

```js
return () => {                        
    items.forEach((item) => {
        observer.unobserve(item)
    })
                                                            
    observer.disconnect()
                        
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems from the docs that disconnect, stops all elements in one go, whereas unobserve you need to specify each target.

`disconnect`

> The IntersectionObserver method disconnect() stops watching all of its
> target elements for visibility changes.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/disconnect)

`unobserve`

> The IntersectionObserver method unobserve() instructs the
> IntersectionObserver to stop observing the specified target element.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve)